# Validate JSON in XML using regex in XSD

Tags: regex, json, xsd

I want to validate JSON using regex in XSD using pattern:

```
<xs:simpleType name="json">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value='/\A("([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"|-?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?|true|false|null|\[(?:(?1)(?:,(?1))*)?\s*\]|\{(?:\s*"([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"\s*:(?1)(?:,\s*"([^"\\]*|\\["\\bfnrt\/]|\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*"\s*:(?1))*)?\s*\})\Z/is'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But (?1) is not supported in xs:pattern. Please help.

Comment: Just don't... And I really doubt XSD supports recursive regex.

Answer (score 3):

Since XSD pattern doesn't support recursive regex `(?1)`, you should **not even attempt** to do the validation with its meager regex support. It is just plain impossible, and any attempt to write a regex will not validate all inputs correctly.

I suggest that the validation of JSON is done separately, possibly with a JSON parsing library, or in an environment where the regex engine supports recursive regex.